# Add a variable into a list with Python

Tags: python, list, format

I want add a variable to some of the items in mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']. I tried something like this example...

```
for direction in ['Up', 'Down']:
    mylist = ['A{}', 'B', 'C{}', 'D', 'E'].format(direction)
    for x in mylist:
        print x
```

I want the output to be the following...

```
AUp
B
CUp
D
E
ADown
B
CDown
D
E
```

However, this isn't working. Is there a best way to add a variable in a list?

Comment: You need to describe the problem. "However, this isn't working." isn't very helpful.

Comment: `format` works on a string, not a list

Comment: `print x.format(direction)` in your 2nd `for` loop and remove the `format` from your list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot "vectorize" this formatting operation! It should be operated upon each string individually.

```
data = ['A{}', 'B', 'C{}', 'D', 'E']
direction = ['Up', 'Down']

for d in direction:
     print(*[x.format(d) for x in data], sep='\n')

AUp
B
CUp
D
E
ADown
B
CDown
D
E
```

Iterate over `direction`, and call `format` in a loop. If you're using python3, you can use the `*` iterable unpacking with a `sep` argument.

For python2, add a `__future__` import statement at the top of your file, like this -

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

You can then use the `print` function to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
mylist = ['A{}', 'B', 'C{}', 'D', 'E']
for direction in ['Up', 'Down']:
    for x in mylist:
        x = x.format(direction)
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

With keeping the original `mylist`:

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for direction in ['Up', 'Down']:
    for x in mylist:
        print x + direction if x in ['A', 'C'] else x
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have little different approach , You can do without loop without
>   using two loop in just one line but result will be in list format :

```
 print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:y.format(x),data)),direction)))
```

output:

```
[['AUp', 'B', 'CUp', 'D', 'E'], ['ADown', 'B', 'CDown', 'D', 'E']]
```

But if you want each element in new line then you have to iterate :

```
for k in direction:
    for i in data:
        print(i.format(k))
```

output:

```
AUp
B
CUp
D
E
ADown
B
CDown
D
E
```